# Will Invalid click activity on Ads download from play store suspend the account?

Tags: android, admob, ads, adsense

Invalid click activity on Ads that downloaded from play store will suspend the google adsense account or not?

Answer (score 0):

From Google's support page [here:](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3342054?hl=en)

> If we observe high levels of invalid activity on your account, we may suspend or disable the account to protect our advertisers and users. Due to invalid activity, you may also see a difference between your estimated and finalized earnings.

Comment: My question is that if app is in production (live on play store) then the invalid click on ads will suspend the google account adsense or not?

Comment: If there are a lot of invalid clicks, it will be suspended.

Comment: If some one intentionally click multiple time live ads for his revenge than the owner of app will be affected. The app owner has no any fault but also he will be suspended. How will that be handle by Google Adsense? Do you have any idea? @Nabin Bhandari

Comment: Actually Google hasn't disclosed how they detect unusual behavior. I guess they are smart enough to handle such situations.